# C# Issue sending and receiving data

Tags: c#, tcpclient, tcplistener

I know that this is a very discussed topic, but i'm facing a strange behavior from my code.

Making some tests I found that everything goes perfectly for some clients but others simply can't receive and send data through my custom Client design `TCPClient` based.
I can't confirm if this issue is caused by `VPN` or `NATs` connections although many Users can access my server from this connection types.

I' ve been reading about `TCPClient` and `TCPListener` in .Net and searching issues like mine but no luck. Everything I got are poor examples.
I will appreciate any help, even book references for network advanced programming.

Here is my code. Most stable up to date

**Cliente.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace netComunicator
{
    public class Client:IDisposable
    {
        int BufferSize { get { return 16384; } }

        /// <summary>
        /// .NET TcpClient for receive and send methods
        /// </summary>
        public TcpClient NetClient = new TcpClient();


        /// <summary>
        /// Externl buffer to store incoming data
        /// This buffers get clear when EOS secuence is present on it
        /// </summary>
        List<byte> ExternBuffer = new List<byte>();
        

        /// <summary>
        /// Remote port
        /// </summary>
        public string Port { get; set; }


        /// <summary>
        /// MAC address from client
        /// </summary>
        public string ClientMac { get; set; }


        /// <summary>
        /// Client IP
        /// </summary>
        public string ClientIp { get; set; }


        /// <summary>
        /// Cifrado
        /// Use NETSID as public key and his first 128 bits as IV
        /// </summary>
        private NetCipher Cipher { get; set; }

        
        /// <summary>
        /// Shared network session id
        /// </summary>
        public string NETSID { get; set; }


        #region delegados y eventos
        public delegate void NoConnection(string noConnectedClient);
        public delegate void ObjectDataReceived(object data, Client client);
        public delegate void ClientDisconnected(Client client);

        public event ClientDisconnected OnClientDisconnected;
        public event ObjectDataReceived OnObjectDataReceived;
        public event NoConnection OnFailConnectTo;
        #endregion

        public NetworkStream NetStream;

        CancellationTokenSource CTS;
        CancellationToken Token;

        CancellationTokenSource CancelKAS;
        CancellationToken CancelKASToken;



        /// <summary>
        /// Max lost count of KEEP_ALIVE
        /// </summary>
        const int MAX_KEEP_ALIVE_COUNT = 30;

        /// <summary>
        /// Current lost KEEP_ALIVE_SIGNAL
        /// </summary>
        int CURRENT_KEEP_ALIVE_SIGNAL_COUNT = 0;

        public Client(byte[] NETSID)
        {
            CTS = new CancellationTokenSource();
            Token = CTS.Token;

            CancelKAS = new CancellationTokenSource();
            CancelKASToken = CancelKAS.Token;

            ClientMac = GetMac();

            if (NETSID != null)
            {
                Cipher = new NetCipher(NETSID);
                this.NETSID = new Guid(NETSID).ToString();
            }
        }


        public void StartClient()
        {
            try
            {
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Receive(), Token);
            }
            catch { }
        }

        public void StopClient()
        {
            CTS.Cancel();
        }

        public void StartKeepAliveSignal()
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            { 
                while (!CancelKASToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    if (CURRENT_KEEP_ALIVE_SIGNAL_COUNT == MAX_KEEP_ALIVE_COUNT)
                    {
                        OnClientDisconnected?.BeginInvoke(this, null, null);
                        Dispose();
                    }

                    Send("KEEP_ALIVE");
                    CURRENT_KEEP_ALIVE_SIGNAL_COUNT++;

                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }, CancelKASToken);
        }

        public void StoptKeepAliveSignal()
        {
            CancelKAS.Cancel();
        }
        

        static string GetLocalIPAddress()
        {
            var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
                if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                    return ip.ToString();
            throw new Exception("No network adapters with an IPv4 address in the system!");
        }

        string GetMac()
        {
            NetworkInterface[] nics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
            var mac = nics.Where(n => n.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up).FirstOrDefault();
            if (mac != null)
                return mac.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
            return "";
        }
        

        void CloseConnection()
        {
            NetClient.Close();
        }
        
        public void Dispose()
        {
            try
            {
                StoptKeepAliveSignal();
                StopClient();
                CloseConnection();
            }
            catch{ }
        }
        

        async public Task<bool> Connect(string ip, int port, bool initKAS = true)
        {
            return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    NetClient.Connect(ip, port);

                    Guid guid = new Guid(NETSID);

                    if (NetStream == null)
                    {
                        NetStream = NetClient.GetStream();
                        Cipher = new NetCipher(guid.ToByteArray());
                    }

                    List<byte> initdata = new List<byte>();
                    initdata.AddRange(NetComTools.wellcomeMsg);
                    initdata.AddRange(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ClientMac));
                    initdata.AddRange(guid.ToByteArray());
                    
                    NetStream.Write(initdata.ToArray(), 0, initdata.Count);

                    StartClient();

                    // if required KEEP_ALIVE_SIGNAL on
                    if (initKAS)
                        StartKeepAliveSignal();

                    ClientIp = ip;

                    return true;
                }
                catch
                {
                    // Notificar que no se pudo establecer conexion
                    OnFailConnectTo?.Invoke(ip);
                }
                return false;
            });
        }
        
        public void Receive()
        {
            while (!Token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                try
                {
                    byte[] buff = new byte[BufferSize];
                    int bytesReaded = NetStream.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length);
                    byte[] bytesFromBuffer = buff.Take(bytesReaded).ToArray();

                    CURRENT_KEEP_ALIVE_SIGNAL_COUNT = 0;

                    ExternBuffer.AddRange(bytesFromBuffer);

                    // Determine if current received bytes have End Of Secuence byte array
                    bool isEOS = IsEndOfSecuence(ExternBuffer);

                    if (isEOS)
                    {
                        // Secuence separator takes inside EOS and passing ExternBuffer
                        // split current buffer in N subsecuences.
                        // This because in one buffer read, can be more than one message delimited by EOS
                        List<byte[]> secuences = SecuenceSeparator(ExternBuffer);

                        ExternBuffer.Clear();

                        foreach (byte[] secuence in secuences)
                        {
                            byte[] decompress = Decompress(secuence);
                            byte[] decipher = Cipher.Decrypt(decompress);
                            object data = Serializer.Deserialize(decipher);
                            OnObjectDataReceived?.BeginInvoke(data, this, null, null);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    Dispose();
                    OnClientDisconnected?.Invoke(this);
                    return;
                }

                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// If bytes[] have an EOS secuence return true
        /// </summary>
        bool IsEndOfSecuence(byte[] bytes)
        {
            int secuencelen = bytes.Length - 1;
            int checkSum = NetComTools.EOS.Length - 1;
            int EOSLen = checkSum;
            int trys = 0;

            for (int i = secuencelen; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (trys <= EOSLen)
                {
                    if (checkSum == 0)
                        return true;
                    if (bytes[i] == NetComTools.EOS[checkSum])
                        checkSum--;
                    else
                        checkSum = NetComTools.EOS.Length - 1;
                }
                else
                    return false;

                trys++;
            }
            return false;
        }
        bool IsEndOfSecuence(List<byte> bytes)
        {
            int secuencelen = bytes.Count - 1;
            int checkSum = NetComTools.EOS.Length - 1;
            int EOSLen = checkSum;
            int trys = 0;

            for (int i = secuencelen; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (trys <= EOSLen)
                {
                    if (checkSum == 0)
                        return true;
                    if (bytes[i] == NetComTools.EOS[checkSum])
                        checkSum--;
                    else
                        checkSum = NetComTools.EOS.Length - 1;
                }
                else
                    return false;

                trys++;
            }
            return false;
        }
        

        List<byte[]> SecuenceSeparator(byte[] data)
        {
            List<byte[]> subsecuences = new List<byte[]>();
            List<byte> externBuff = new List<byte>(data);

            int inc = 0;
            int secuencelen = externBuff.Count;
            int lastpos = 0;
            //40  =  15 + datos, 5 + eos, 15 + datos, 5 + eos
            for (int i = 0; i < secuencelen; i++)
            {
                if (externBuff[i] == NetComTools.EOS[inc])
                {
                    inc++;
                    if (inc == NetComTools.EOS.Length)
                    {
                        List<byte> sub_nsecuence = new List<byte>();
                        int elements = i + 1 - lastpos - NetComTools.EOS.Length;
                        byte[] matchsecuence = new byte[elements];
                        externBuff.CopyTo(lastpos, matchsecuence, 0, elements);
                        sub_nsecuence.AddRange(matchsecuence);
                        subsecuences.Add(sub_nsecuence.ToArray());
                        inc = 0;
                        lastpos = i + 1;
                    }
                }
                else
                    inc = 0;

            }
            return subsecuences;
        }
        List<byte[]> SecuenceSeparator(List<byte> externBuff)
        {
            List<byte[]> subsecuences = new List<byte[]>();

            int inc = 0;
            int secuencelen = externBuff.Count;
            int lastpos = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < secuencelen; i++)
            {
                if (externBuff[i] == NetComTools.EOS[inc])
                {
                    inc++;
                    if (inc == NetComTools.EOS.Length)
                    {
                        List<byte> sub_nsecuence = new List<byte>();
                        int elements = i + 1 - lastpos - NetComTools.EOS.Length;
                        byte[] matchsecuence = new byte[elements];
                        externBuff.CopyTo(lastpos, matchsecuence, 0, elements);
                        sub_nsecuence.AddRange(matchsecuence);
                        subsecuences.Add(sub_nsecuence.ToArray());
                        inc = 0;
                        lastpos = i + 1;
                    }
                }
                else
                    inc = 0;

            }
            return subsecuences;
        }
        
        public void Send(object data)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] objDatabyte = Serializer.Serialize(data);
                byte[] cipher = Cipher.Encrypt(objDatabyte);
                byte[] compressed = Compress(cipher);
                NetStream.Write(compressed, 0, compressed.Length);
                NetStream.Write(NetComTools.EOS, 0, NetComTools.EOS.Length);
            }
            catch
            {
                OnClientDisconnected?.Invoke(this);
                Dispose();
            }
        }

        public static byte[] Compress(byte[] raw)
        {
            using (MemoryStream msw = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (GZipStream gzip = new GZipStream(msw, CompressionMode.Compress))
                    gzip.Write(raw, 0, raw.Length);
                return msw.ToArray();
            }
        }

        public static byte[] Decompress(byte[] gzipraw)
        {
            using (GZipStream msw = new GZipStream(new MemoryStream(gzipraw), CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    int readed;
                    while ((readed = msw.ReadByte()) != -1)
                        ms.WriteByte((byte)readed);
                    return ms.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static class Serializer
    {
        public static byte[] Serialize(object anySerializableObject)
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                (new BinaryFormatter()).Serialize(memoryStream, anySerializableObject);
                return memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }

        public static object Deserialize(byte[] message)
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(message))
            {
                BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter();
                memoryStream.Position = 0;
                return b.Deserialize(memoryStream);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**Server.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.Linq;
namespace netComunicator
{
    public class Server
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Connected Clients
        /// </summary>
        public ConcurrentBag<Client> Clients = new ConcurrentBag<Client>();
        

        /// <summary>
        /// .NET TcpListenet
        /// </summary>
        public TcpListener Host;


        CancellationTokenSource CTS;
        CancellationToken Token;


        #region Delegados y Eventos
        public delegate void ClientConnected(Client client);
        public delegate void ClientDisconnected(Client client);

        public event ClientConnected OnClientConnected;
        public event ClientDisconnected OnClientDisconnected;
        #endregion

        
        public Server(int port)
        {
            CTS = new CancellationTokenSource();
            Token = CTS.Token;
            try
            {
                Host = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(NetComTools.thisClientIP), port);
                Host.Start();

                try  { Task.Factory.StartNew(() => AcceptIncoming(), Token); }  catch (Exception ex) {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ec)
            {
                throw ec;
            }
        }
        

        public void SendTo(Client client, object data)
        {
            Client cl = Clients.Where(c => c.Equals(client)).FirstOrDefault();
            cl?.Send(data);
        }


        public void SendAll(object data)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                foreach (Client client in Clients)
                    client.Send(data);
            });
        }

        
        void AcceptIncoming()
        {
            while (!Token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                try
                {
                        AsyncCallback acb = new AsyncCallback(PerformConnection);
                        Host.BeginAcceptSocket(acb, null);

                    Thread.Sleep(10);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }

            }
        }

        void PerformConnection(IAsyncResult res)
        {
            TcpClient tempClient = null;
            try
            {
                tempClient = Host.EndAcceptTcpClient(res);
                NetworkStream ns;
                ns = tempClient.GetStream();

                byte[] initData = new byte[NetComTools.wellcomeMsg.Length + 28];

                ns.Read(initData, 0, initData.Length);
                
                byte[] wellcome = new byte[NetComTools.wellcomeMsg.Length];
                byte[] mac = new byte[12];
                byte[] netsidfromclient = new byte[16];
                List<byte> ini = new List<byte>(initData);
                ini.CopyTo(0, wellcome, 0, 4);
                ini.CopyTo(4, mac, 0, 12);
                ini.CopyTo(16, netsidfromclient, 0, 16);

                if (WellcomeOk(wellcome))
                {
                    
                    Client newClient = new Client(netsidfromclient)
                    {
                        ClientIp = tempClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().Split(':')[0],
                        Port = tempClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().Split(':')[1],
                        NetStream = ns,
                        ClientMac = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(mac),
                    };
                    
                    Clients.Add(newClient);
                    newClient.NetClient = tempClient;
                    newClient.OnClientDisconnected += newClient_OnClientDisconnected;
                    newClient.StartClient();
                    OnClientConnected?.BeginInvoke(newClient, null, null);
                }
                else
                    tempClient.Close();
                
            }
            catch {if( tempClient != null) tempClient.Close(); return; }
        }

        bool WellcomeOk(byte[] wellcomeFromNet)
        {
            if (wellcomeFromNet.Length != NetComTools.wellcomeMsg.Length)
                return false;
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < wellcomeFromNet.Length; i++)
                    if (wellcomeFromNet[i] != NetComTools.wellcomeMsg[i])
                        return false;
            }
            return true;
        }



        void newClient_OnClientDisconnected(Client client)
        {
            client.OnClientDisconnected -= newClient_OnClientDisconnected;
            Clients = RemoveClientFromList(client);
            OnClientDisconnected?.Invoke(client);
        }


        ConcurrentBag<Client> RemoveClientFromList(Client client)
        {
            ConcurrentBag<Client> Acl = new ConcurrentBag<Client>();
            return new ConcurrentBag<Client>(Clients.Where(c => c != client));
        }


        public void StopListener()
        {
            Host.Stop();
            CTS.Cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? And where are they happening?

Comment: Im not sure where the error reside but i'm think is from the external buffer lista. I'm aware if I send two chunks of data they come arrive together. And I need a way to split it. There's when external buffer works.

Comment: `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Receive(), Token);` -- why? Isn't there a `ReceiveAsync` or at least a `BeginReceive`? This is old-school: `return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>...`, use `await Task.Run(()=>...`

Comment: There are so many things wrong with how you do Tasks. This needs to be a re-write using Task properly. You don't await on anything important. You should study up on the `async/await` pattern... or at the very least, use `Begin...End...` methods.

Comment: Yes, it is. I go that way to put a "never ending" loop in that task. Is other way to go with it?

Comment: @Andy but you think this is part of the error or is all?

Comment: Yes. At the very least your code will become easier to read and maintain. Right now there are so many things being done in an unorthodox manner. No one will be able to help you because the weird patterns you are using. If you do things the proper way, chances are your errors will disappear, if not, at least we will be able to tell you what you need to do to fix them. Right now what you need to do is learn how Async/Await works and apply it to this code.

Comment: Ok, hands to work then... I'll be back